# Browser Back Button issue in asp.net

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, asp.net-ajax

I have registration form, suppose there are 5 fields, and all are required i.e. mandatory.
My problem is that when user login & fill 2 fields of that registration form & click browser back button, then I want to restrict user to same form & Show requiredField Validator messages of incomplete fields. So How can I fire Validation on browser back button & restrict user on same form.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot affect browser behavior when the user clicks the Back button.

Comment: My client want to fill all entries by user & then submit data. So he want to disable back button. He is forcing user to fill all details. & lOGIN means it is special ID given by Client company to customer, So there is no database issue.

Answer (score 1):

The correct solution is to check right after user have been login, if he has complete the registration entries on database, and if not you redirect him to fill that data.

From your comments, to alert them a solution is to capture the `onbeforeunload` and check there if they have fill out everything or not, show your message.

Simple example, you just need here to place your conditions.

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    return 'You have unsaved changes!';
}
```

Comment: No its not like that, My clien want to fill all entries by user & then submit data. So he want to disable back button.

Comment: @ConstantLearner tell him that this is impossible - you can not disable the back button. Try to understand what I have write.

Comment: Client is forcing user to fill all details. & LOGIN means it is special ID given by Client company to customer, So there is no database issue.

Comment: @ConstantLearner And where do you save all that entries ?

Comment: I have seperate table of REGISTRATION. Will you pls tell me that is there any solution to restrict user to same page & force him to fill all entries & If he click back button then alert him with error i.e. incomplete messages

Comment: @ConstantLearner To alert them is possible, I update my answer. (To force them is not possible)

Comment: I have tried onbeforeunload but it does not work... Will you pls elaborate if I miss something... & One main thing is that He dont want javascipt msg's for incomplete field , He needs same required field validator's RED messages..

Comment: @ Aristos : Thanks for information, I am very new to ASP.Net, But you provide good info.... So Should I tell him that It's Impossible..??

Answer (score 1):

You can't disable the back button (see the other answers and their comments).

What you *can* do is check on every page whether the user is logged in. If not, redirect him to your login page. This way the user can't access the site without logging in, which I guess is what your client is really after.

Comment: @ Hans Kesting: No dear, he just want to force users to complete registration !!!!!

Comment: @ConstantLearner - logging in, completing registration: you can use the same methods.